# Set range slider progress on keyup

Tags: javascript

So i got input type range, which works fine and input box, when user types number 10-500 It sets value on range and I need to set the color of progress in range. Now its showing up the previous value.

```js
var textInputKg = document.getElementById("text");
var rangeInputKg = document.getElementById("range");

function rangeProgress(to, from) {
  var min = rangeInputKg.min;
  var max = rangeInputKg.max;
  var value = rangeInputKg.value;
  var p = ((value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;
  rangeInputKg.style.backgroundImage =
    "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, " +
    "color-stop(" +
    p +
    "%, yellow), " +
    "color-stop(" +
    p +
    "%, black)" +
    ")";
  to.value = from.value;
}

function delay(fn, ms) {
  let timer = 0;
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(fn.bind(this, ...args), ms || 0);
  };
}

rangeInputKg.addEventListener("input", e => {
  rangeProgress(textInputKg, rangeInputKg);
});

textInputKg.addEventListener(
  "keyup",
  delay(e => {
    rangeProgress(rangeInputKg, textInputKg);
    console.log(textInputKg.value);
  }, 500)
);
```

```css
#range {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<input id="range" type="range" max="500" min="10" value="10" autocomplete="off">
<input id="text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `from` parameter value

```
var p = ((value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;
```

to

```
var p = ((from.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;
```

```js
var textInputKg = document.getElementById("text");
var rangeInputKg = document.getElementById("range");

function rangeProgress(to, from) {
  var min = rangeInputKg.min;
  var max = rangeInputKg.max;
  var p = ((from.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;
  rangeInputKg.style.backgroundImage =
    "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, " +
    "color-stop(" +
    p +
    "%, yellow), " +
    "color-stop(" +
    p +
    "%, black)" +
    ")";
  to.value = from.value;
}

function delay(fn, ms) {
  let timer = 0;
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(fn.bind(this, ...args), ms || 0);
  };
}

rangeInputKg.addEventListener("input", e => {
  rangeProgress(textInputKg, rangeInputKg);
});

textInputKg.addEventListener(
  "keyup",
  delay(e => {
    rangeProgress(rangeInputKg, textInputKg);
  }, 500)
);
```

```css
#range {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<input id="range" type="range" max="500" min="10" value="10" autocomplete="off">
<input id="text">
```